# WCF Service not publishing the wsdl

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, service, wsdl

I am pretty new to WCF Services but I never got my head around the bindings and all that. The service I have right now, works fine if tested in WCFTestClient but does not expose WSDL for other applications to use. I am not sure how it is done. Here is the code:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="DefaultBindingConfig">
      <!--<security mode="none">
        <transport clientCredentialType="none" />
      </security>-->

    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="Service.SecurityService">
    <endpoint address="" 
              name="SecurityServiceEndpoint" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="DefaultBindingConfig" 
              contract="Service.Contracts.ISecurityService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

```
[ServiceContract]
  public interface ISecurityService
  {
    [OperationContract]
    ApplicationSecurity GetFunctionsAllowedForUser(string userName, string applicationName);    
}
```

How can I make it so that this service exposes the WSDL? I am pretty new to this.

Answer (score 0):

The following line should expose the metadata for the wsdl:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
```

In your browser, go to whatever the web address of the `svc` is and add `?wsdl` to the end of it.

```
http://localhost:<Port>/<OptionalFolders/>MyService.svc?wsdl
```

If everything's working correctly, you should have a bunch of XML.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that but when I go to localhost:8000/Service.svc?wsdl , it gives me a 400 Bad Request Error. I am not sure what is causing that to go wrong :/

Comment: Well, your port may be different than mine. Go to Project Properties -> Web. See if there's a specified port, or a specific folder address. Or better yet, use the address that's in the WCFTestClient and just append `?wsdl` to the end.

Comment: Yeah, I have put the port for the service same as the one I have here. However, it still says 400 Bad Request error. I have tried going to /mex or ?wsdl but both return the same :/

Could it be something to do with the server that I am running it on?

Comment: No idea. That's not something that I can help with. Sorry, and best of luck!